# Release management using SBT

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I am new to Scala, we are doing a prototype using Scala and SBT as build tool. 
Can someone help me how to release WAR files using SBT to artifactory. 
In JAVA I am using maven and specifying artifactory urls in settings.xml and I am specifying snapshot or release versions in pom file. 
I have no clue how to achieve this functionality using SBT.

Thanks in advance

Prasad

Comment: Check first http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ajozwik said in his comments, check the docs first so you understand the basics, the docs are pretty good these days: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html

For packaging .war artifacts from sbt, I think the xsbt-web-plugin is your friend: https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin